# How to remove newline characters in csv columns, without removing the endrow newline character?

Tags: python, csv

So I have this dataset where there are sometimes random newline characters entered into some cells, and I need to delete them.

this is what I've tried:

```
with open ('filepath') as inf, open('filepath', 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        outf.write(line.replace('\n', ''))
```

Unfortunately, this removed ALL newline characters, including the ones at the end of the row, which turns my csv file into a big one-liner

Does anyone know how I can only delete the random newline characters and not the 'real' endline characters?

Edit: If it helps, each 'real' new line starts with a 6 digit string of numbers (besides for the header line). Maybe some regex pattern that looks ahead to detect if there's some number string could work?

Edit2: I've tried using pandas to edit it with:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filepath)

for i in df.columns:
    if df[i].dtype==np.object:
        df[i] = df[i].str.replace('\n','')
```

weirdly, this works if I copy the stuff inside the .csv into a new text file, but it doesn't work on my original csv file, and I'm not sure why.

Final Edit:

So big thanks to DDS for his help. Managed to get it to work using this:

```
num_cols = 48

buf = ""

with open (filepath) as inf, open (filepath, 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        if len(line.split(',')) < num_cols:
            buf += line.replace('\n', '')
            if len(buf.split(',')) == num_cols:
                outf.write(buf+'\n')
            else: continue
            buf = ""
        else:
            outf.write(line)
```

Comment: You're iterating over file line by line which means that there's only one newline character possible in line, at the end of this line.

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you mean Olvin. I'm not sure how else to go about this though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the number of fields per line and no field contains the csv separator (comma): you could do like this:

```py
    number_of_columns_in_the_table = 5 #assuming a line has 5 columns
    with open ('filepath') as inf, open('filepath', 'w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            #check if the number of "splits equals the nummber of fields"
            if len(line.split(',')) < number_of_columns_in_the_table
               
 outf.write(line.replace('\n', ''))
            else:
                outf.write(line)
```

EDIT

```
number_of_columns_in_the_table = 5 #assuming a line has 5 columns
    with open ('filepath') as inf, open('filepath', 'w') as outf:
        for line in inf:
            #check if the number of "splits equals the nummber of fields"
            if len(line.split(',')) < number_of_columns_in_the_table
               buf += line.replace('\n', '');
           if len(line.split(',')) == number_of_columns_in_the_table
               outf.write( buf)
            else:
                outf.write(line)
```

Comment: This is almost working! At the moment it is merging all the affected rows into one row. I think this is because it is checking the split length, then replacing the first  \n, but then when it checks the next line with the 'real' newline, it is detecting it as being too short (because it read half the line previously)

Comment: Okay, so it looks like now the "outf.write(line)" is triggering when the outf.write(buf) triggers, resulting in it writing the old broken line and the fixed line

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can achieve this.

1. Since you're only concerned about the last occurrence of newline char to be present, you can add a newline character at the end of the replaced string

```
    with open ('filepath') as inf, open('filepath', 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        outf.write(line.replace('\n', '') + '\n')
```

2. You can keep a count of the newline characters present and make use of the [count argument of the replace method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to pass `n - 1` as the number of the newline characters to replace

```
    with open ('filepath') as inf, open('filepath', 'w') as outf:
    for line in inf:
        outf.write(line.replace('\n', '', line.count('\n') - 1))
```

3. Make use of the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) library of python to do substitution by having a check ahead to replace the newline character iff there a succeeding newline.

```
    import re
    result = re.sub( '\n*(?=.*\n)','' ,'ansd\nasdn\naskd\n')
    print(result)
    'ansdasdnaskd\n'
```

Comment: So with the first two bits of code, because we're reading in the csv line by line, it replaces the \n with " ", and then immediately adds it back in, because it detects that its the end of the line due to the \n. Same with the line.count.

For the 3rd one, the result i'm getting is 'ansdasdnaskd'. This one looks promising though!

Comment: As I go over the comments posted on the question, I realise that you're trying to read lines . Could you please check if the data which you see in the file is having newline characters around the commas ? If yes, we can set a few conditions around that as well to ensure the correct newline characters are targeted. Also, could you please let me know what python version are you using ?

Comment: So the newline characters are inserted randomly in certain fields. Here's an example:

123123,Test, 12/12/2020,ASG305, Doggo A \nDoggoB, etc, etc, end. After 'end' theres the newline that I want to keep, so that the date fits the columns. Also i'm using 3.8.5

Answer (score 0):

First control your line that is empty or not than write the line

```
 for line in inf:
    if len(line.strip()) == 0:
          outf.write(line.replace('\n', ''))
    else:
        outf.write(line)
```

Comment: this doesn't change anything, unfortunately

Comment: Did you control which file did you write, I control the file and I works succesfuly